# Number of permutations with balanced middle element

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $v$ be a permutation of $\{1,2,\cdots,2n+1\}$ where $n$ is odd, such that the middle element $v_{n+1}$ satisfies the following: the number of elements to the right of $v_{n+1}$ that are less than $v_{n+1}$ is equal to the number of elements to the left of $v_{n+1}$ which are greater. In math language: $|\{i: \ i>n, v_i<v_{n+1}\}|=|\{i: \ i<n, v_i>v_{n+1}\}|$. For example if $n=1$, then there are two possibilities $v=123$ and $v=321$, whereas $v=132$ is not. Letting $V_n$ be the set of all such $v$, what is the cardinality of $V_n$? In the above example $|V_1|=2$.

I've tried coming up with recurrences but they all seem very ugly. Are the elements of $V_n$ in bijection with some nice other combinatorial object?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Sorry I have dyslexia or something. Corrected

Comment: From your positive reaction to Brian's answer, it seems that where it says $v_n$ and $n$, you meant $v_{n+1}$ and $n+1$?

Comment: Note that you can use `\left` and `\right` also for vertical bars to make their size adjust to the content.

Comment: Now you've changed $v_n$ to $v_{n+1}$ but not $n$ to $n+1$?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that there are $k$ ‘bad’ elements on each side of $v_{n+1}$. If we interchange the bad elements on the left with those on the right, we end up with $v_{n+1}$ still in the middle position, with all elements correctly placed in relation to it, so $v_{n+1}$ must necessarily be $n+1$.

Pick any $k$ elements of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and any $k$ elements of $\{n+2,\ldots,2n+1\}$ and interchange them; there are $\binom{n}k^2$ ways to do this. Now permute the left $n$ and the right $n$ numbers independently; there are $n!^2$ ways to do this. Altogether you end up with

$$n!^2\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k^2=n!^2\binom{2n}n=(2n)!$$

possible permutations.

You can derive this result more directly by noting that if you place $n+1$ in the middle, *any* permutation of the remaining $2n$ integers necessarily has as many large ones on the left as it has small ones on the right.

Comment: @jim: You’re welcome.